# Browsers stop loading photos from cache after a 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, html

It's hard to pick the right code to describe this question.

I have thumbnails, loaded with photos from server right on page load.
When you click on a thumbnail it will change the large `preview` container's `img` source.
What happens is :

1. website starts loading
2. all thumbnails get their photos in place
3. I start playing with the thumbs and it works fast - i click a thumb and the `preview` image changes *right away*. **not reloaded from the internet**
   again and again
4. website for some reason keep loading(i see on the address bar
5. **at the moment** it finish loading - the thumbs will become slow -  now i click a thumb and the image will be loaded from the internet(2 seconds).

So my gallery become useless after 2-4 seconds.

Here is the code that change photo + a thumb html for example.

```
    function thumb(arg){

       var pid= "productPhoto"+arg ;
       var prvimgShow = document.getElementById(pid).src;
       var previmgShow = document.getElementById("preview").src;
       if(prvimgShow===previmgShow)return;
       currentPP=document.getElementById(pid);
         $("#preview").attr("src",prvimgShow);
    }
     <div class="thumb  shadow"    onclick="thumb(1)"  ><img id="productPhoto1"/></div>
```

What can cause the cache to stop working ? do i overload it somehow later ? ( i don't think i am )

Comment: Without the code which shows the example we will be unable to diagnose the grand overall problem without having a concise example.

Where is the functions which are called etc..

If I put this code in jsFiddle do I have everything I need to replicate and solve the issue?

Comment: the code is huge and as i said i can not select a specific line because i don't know which. I was expecting to hear a list of things that might cause this in which i can check instantly. What can cause images to reload from server suddenly?

Comment: Then what do you want US to do exactly but look at this question and say ___

Comment: Yea, I will try and do that, admittingly I must struggle trying to be a human... . Its so... Good day.

Comment: thanks a lot for trying

Comment: There is no try....

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in chat perhaps? Otherwise you should vote to remove / close the question if you don't need it.